# Unable to upgrade XAMPP

Tags: xampp

I've spent the last 3 years attempting to get a website partner for an International trading website, but now I have given up on that idea and decided to learn development alone, although still open to a partnership, however at first I installed XAMPP version 1.7.7 and added a CodeIgniter based registration script, but now get this message - Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings. Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\system\database\DB_driver.php Line Number: 124

With that problem, together with the CodeIgniter changes and the XAMPP new version 5.6.8 I've decided to upgrade both. However I want to keep the old versions to enable retrieving data that has been entered into the old versions. I prefer to keep the old versions separate so that I know what portions are old and new.

I have attempted to change the name of the old version of XAMPP but I'm unable to do that and get this response - "The action can't be completed because the folder or a file is open in another program." I guess the referred folders are "Apache" and "MySQL". I've gone into XAMPP Control Panel and note "Apache" and "MySQL" are "Running" and if I click "Stop" I get ERROR messages and they don't stop. I've done some research and found that I need to be logged in as "Administrator". I've gone into Win7 Control Panel - User Accounts - and found that I'm listed as "Administrator" password protected. I've tried rebooting but that does not help. I now need guidance but open to suggestions on alternative methods to upgrade that has the same effects as in the previous paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Being an administrator under XAMPP and an administrator under Win7 are two different things.

Right click the control panel exe file in XAMPP folder and click "Run as administrator" and then Exit the control panel.

If the XAMPP control panel is running the above can't be done and I found I had to reboot to start the control panel fresh, then carry out the above.

Once all of that was done, I renamed the XAMPP folder.